# Compile time of native dependencies takes too much time in node

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, yarnpkg

I setup a gitlab runner which builds my node project. One dependency is `nodegit` which takes `480 seconds` every time I build my app.

```
$ electron-builder install-app-deps
  • electron-builder  version=22.9.1
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=nodegit@0.27.0 platform=darwin arch=x64
  • rebuilding native dependency  name=nodegit version=0.27.0
Done in 480.36s.
```

Is there any way to cache building these native dependencies? I found [prebuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prebuild) which created a `tar.gz` file. But I am not sure how I can make my project use this specific prebuilt file. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Consider configuring a [GitLab CI/CD Cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) on the built `node_modules` directory or whatever the built dependency directory is.

Comment: Thank you! That would be a massive improvement! Is there a non Gitlab solution available via `prebuild`?

Comment: From its description, it seems so. The documentation does not lend itself to a quick explanation, though - it seems unclear how it interops with `node_modules`. Most CI/CD systems support caching of built/fetched dependencies, and locally these would be cached as well. I am not particularly sure `prebuild` is _necessary_ here. However, if you're specifically after `prebuild`, I would recommend updating your question to reflect it. If you provide more details on your GitLab CI/CD setup (a minimal reproduction repository is ideal), I can try optimizing the build time.

Answer (score 1):

A prebuild step needs to be included into the dependent module publishing phase. It should not be executed by the modules consumer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search turned up [Cache dependencies in GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) website which seems to have exactly what you are looking for. Which can also cache Node.js, PHP, Go, and Ruby dependencies between jobs.